# Deploy Web Site Using Team Build 2013

Tags: tfsbuild

I'm coming from a TeamCity background, so this may be a particularly dumb set of questions..

I'm trying, with no luck at all, to customize a XAML build template with a CopyDirectory activity.

I've followed the instructions [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/09/01/tfs-team-build-2010-how-to-place-the-build-output.aspx), but `BuildDetail.DropLocation` doesn't seem to exist so I have hard-coded the source path which doesn't matter beacause that new step isn't being run.

How do I specifiy the build location for Source?  I see the filed on `\\myserver\builds\8\MyTeamProject\MySolution\Bin\_PublishedWebSites\MyApp` but I'd like to be able use something a little less brittle than this.

How do I NOT copy the web.config file, but instead copy and rename my Web.Server1.Config file?

Finally, and most importantly, how do I make it run the CopyDirectory activity at all?  My build completes, but I don't see this in the log and there are no errors or files in my destination folder.

EDIT: Would I be better of just calling a powershell script in the build definition and skipping the workflow piece?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TfcTemplate12.xaml you can use the **Post-build script path** and **Post-build script arguments** build parameters to run a PowerShell script.